# How to make absolute element in relative element responsive?

Tags: css

I have problem with change size while manipulating browser size. I need to keep one column on another so I use relative + absolute combination.

I'm wondering if there is an option with only CSS to make such element responsive.

```
<div class="clock">
 <div id="apDiv3" class="opening">

   <div class="clock">

    <img id="apDiv2" class="clock" src="./assets/stoper-01.png" usemap="#image-map">
    <img id="apDiv1" class="clockArrow" src="./assets/stoper-01-arrow.png">

   <map name="image-map">
    <area area settings>
    ...
   </map>
                   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
div.clock {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img.clock {
  position: relative;
}
.clockArrow {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[image: illustrative picture]

Comment: Can you post the current and the expected results' picture?

Comment: Added illustrative picture

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see you applying even the absolute basics for responsive images yet, there is not even a `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: Seem your code is not complete for recognizing the problem. please show more code about the positioning and scaling of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CSS `calc()` function like the given eg.

```
.top-img{
  ...
  width: calc(var(--background-img-width) - var(--offset));
  ...
}
```

Here, add `--background-ing-width` to your `:root` and apply it in `.background-img`'s  `width`. Then you can add `--offset` in your `:root` and add to `.top-img` as shown and tweak these two variables to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is an option with only CSS to make such element responsive.

Here's a sample:

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: max-content;
}

.circle{
  background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fc1.staticflickr.com%2F1%2F694%2F23104548209_fed5c6d1cd_b.jpg&f=1&nofb=1);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.3vh;
}

.rec{
  flex: 1;
  height: 15vh;
  background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cameraegg.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F09%2FSony-DSC-RX1-Sample-Image.jpg&f=1&nofb=1);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="rec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can make use of viewport `height` and `width` to make the elements responsive. More on units [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).